Websocket - куда денется следующий колбэк, если предыдущий еще не обработался?
У меня есть непонимание работы Websocket
Я использую SDK одной криптобиржи на Python для организации Websocket. Сервер отправляет моему клиенту информацию о случившихся сделках. На каждую сделку срабатывает колбэк, в котором я имею возможность как-то эту информацию обработать (посчитать технические индексы, отправить в базу данных и т.д.). Временная дельта между сделками (а значит и между вызовом колбэка) может быть ничтожной, буквально микросекунды. При этом код, который выполняет колбэк может отрабатывать медленнее, чем придет следующий вызов.
Вопрос - куда денется следующий колбэк? Пропадет? Встанет в какую-то очередь/стэк/буфер и отработает позже? Зависит от реализации или нет?

Попробуйте поставить в колбэк задержку на 30сек, и посмотрети что получится.

Подозреваю, что тут как и с обработкой http запросов зависит от реализации. Веб-серверы бывают однопоточными, многопоточными, асинхронными... Думаю, тут примерно так же, с удовольствием послушаю знатоков темы )

@Kromster я так делал. И что я таким образом пойму? Как я таким образом выясню - тот колбэк (информация о сделке), который пришел через 30 секунд - это реально следующий колбэк или все колбэки за эти 30 сек были утрачены, а через 30 сек я просто получил тот, который пришел первым через 30 сек? Если бы у сделок был сквозной идентификатор - тогда да, было бы на что опереться в анализе, но его нет, точнее есть, но не сквозной, поэтому я не могу понять, как мне поможет такой эксперимент.

@AlexeyTrukhanov А время сделки или чего там, не приходит с колбэком? Если приходит, то сравнить с текущим и посмотреть отставание.

Окей, не 30сек, а 15минут. Уж за 15мин то точно, либо накопится, либо потеряется и это будет очевидно ) Если нет - поднимите второго слушателя со второго ПК и посмотрите кто сколько получит событий (идентичное число и содержимое или нет).

Объединю советы CrazyElf и Kromster, проведу эксперимент и вернусь с отчетом :) Единственное, что смущает. Ну, допустим, я эмпирически выясню, что за те 10-15-20 мин, которые будет спать мой колбэк я не потерял N колбэков, которые пришли за это время. Где гарантии, что если N станет на порядок(-ки) больше в единицу времени (или в абсолютных значениях) я и их не потеряю. То есть эмпирика, это, конечно, уже что-то, но хотелось бы теории. Написать разрабам SDK?

Как говорится, в программировании есть 3 типа задач - для 0, для 1 и для N. Если есть механизм сохранения более 1 колбэка, то скорее всго он регулируется простой настройкой и может быть как 2, так и 1000, так и 4млрд. А дальше, смотрите в сторону TTL, часть колбэков теоретически может отбрасываться по истечение из времени жизни/актуальности.

@CrazyElf хотел бы еще тэгнуть Kromster, надеюсь прочитает. Сделал так - поставил сон на 10 секунд и при каждом колбэке беру таймдельту между текущим временем и временем, которое приходит вместе со сделкой. Колбэки накапливаются! Дельта растет с каждым колбэком, более того, когда я пытаюсь остановить интерпретатор - он продолжает отрабатывать те, которые накопились. Но, вопрос все же остается - сколько оно в состоянии накопить, не теряет ли оно что-то, если приходит, например, сотня сделок в одну микросекунду. Думаю, действительно, нужен второй клиент надолго и сравнивать.

Если речь о таких коротких интервалах и копится несколько в очереди, то особых предпосылок к потере или неадекватно-короткой очереди не видно.

А у этого SDK нет какого-то описания, или может странички на GitHub? Может там всё описано где-то, на самом деле? )

@CrazyElf есть. На GitHub есть страница SDK, а на сайте криптобиржи есть документация для REST API и websocket. Но вот именно на этот вопрос ответа не нашел. Написал им, может прояснят.

Поговорил с разработчиками. У них кэш на серверной стороне, пока не придет подтверждение от клиента, что текущий пуш отработан - следующие кэшируются и высылаются по мере обработки. На мой вопрос имеет ли этот кэш какие-то ограничения, ответ был - "It does, but It will send the data eventually normally". Будем считать, что эксперимент подтвердился теорией :)

Ну вот и оформите это как ответ. Вдруг кому пригодится такое знание )

Особая благодарность выражается CrazyElf и Kromster за ценные советы!
Эксперимент
В колбэк-функцию добавляем sleep(10), тем самым гарантируя, что часть колбэков "упрется" в занятую функцию. Далее сравниваем текущее время и время события, которое приходит вместе с информацией о сделке.
Ожидаем два варианта:

Разница во времени будет постоянной - это будет означать, что колбэки, которые "стучались" в занятую функцию пропали, а в функцию поступают только текущие.
Разница будет нарастать - это будет означать, что колбэки ожидают освобождения функции и поступают в нее по очереди.

В результате получили второй вариант
Фидбэк от разработчиков
На серверной стороне этого Websocket организован кэш. Сервер от клиента получает информацию свободна ли колбэк функция. Если свободна - сервер пушит сообщение, если занята - сообщение отправляется в кэш и ожидает освобождения функции. На мой вопрос - есть ли ограничение у этого кэша ответ был, дословно "It does, but It will send the data eventually normally" (Да, есть, но в конечном итоге он отправит данные в обычном режиме)
Итог
При занятой колбэк-функции колбэки не теряются, а заносятся в кэш и передаются по освобождению функции.
